# Texture streaming in 4K (multi-res)

Tags: c++, opengl

My goal is to stream single channel images in 4K at the highest possible frame rate using OpenGL. This means I have 1 texture which I'm going to update with new content very often.

As for now I'm using PBO's to take advantage of the asynchronous texture download on the GPU. The code is basically:

```
// EACH TIME TEXTURE NEEDS UPDATE
const int pboSize = 4096 * 4096 * 4;

// Bind PBO to texture data source
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pboHandle);
// Discard data in PBO - already sent to GPU
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pboSize, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
// Map buffer to client memory
float* data = static_cast<float*>(glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY));
if (data) {
    std::valarray<IMG_PRECISION>& newImageContent = myImageArray[currentImage];
    // This seems too slow
    std::memcpy(data, &newImageContent[0], newImageContent.size() * sizeof(IMG_PRECISION));
} else {
    std::err << "Failed to map PBO to client memory";
}

// Release the mapped buffer
glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER);

const glm::uvec3& dimensions = _texture->dimensions();
_texture->bind();
// Send async to GPU
glTexSubImage2D(
    _texture->type(),
    0,
    0,
    0,
    GLsizei(dimensions.x),
    GLsizei(dimensions.y),
    GLint(_texture->format()),
    _texture->dataType(),
    nullptr
);

// Set back to normal texture data source
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);
```

This works faster, but not fast enough, than just using `glTexSubImage()` without PBO's. The bottleneck seems to be the `std::memcpy` that takes around `0.0211s`  each frame. I create the texture with `glTexImage2D()` using `GL_R16F` as internal format, `GL_RED` as format and `GL_FLOAT` as data type.

However, I really only need 4K resolution when the texture is very close to the camera, but generating mipmaps at run-time seems too slow. Precomputing them manually would also be pretty annoying since I have lots of these images already in System RAM, loading the mipmaps together with the normal images would be too slow on the CPU side.

Is there any other multi-resolution approach I can't think of right now, or is the only way to get a decent frame rate to use some video codec such as `ffmpeg`? I have a lot of metadata in these images when I load them from disc and would ideally want to avoid that.

**EDIT**:
Target is cross-platform desktop environment using OpenGL 4.5

Comment: Decode frames directly into the mapped buffer?

Comment: How do you mean? I'm not using any encoding

Comment: How are you populating the `std::valarray<IMG_PRECISION>` 'images' in `myImageArray` then?

Comment: I'm reading in data from image files on disc with the help of a library and storing the raw image (grayscale) values as floats in the valarray. How does it make sense to do that decoding into mapped buffer (almost every frame)?

Comment: Saves you the `memcpy()` call.

Answer (score 2):

You want to avoid blocking. Have one thread upload while the other one draws. You should have multiple buffers.

There is a good example on this site that ping-pongs two buffers. http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html

A more advanced multi-threaded approach is found here.

http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2012/presentations/S0356-GTC2012-Texture-Transfers.pdf

Regarding Mipmaps: Don't generate them if you don't need them. Only upload the 0 level.

Additional advice:

- Keep your decoder in another thread.
- Have the decoder buffer a few frames in main memory so the uploads aren't starved waiting for new frames.
- Benchmark. PBO's might not be any faster than glTexSubImage for your case if you end up blocking anyway.
- Watch out for internal conversions. If the internal format is GL_RGB and the glTexSubImage says GL_BGR (for example), it will be doing another copy on the cpu.

Comment: I heard that it's preferred to set the format to GL_BGRA on most GPU:s because then OpenGL doesn't need to convert it. But can't seem to find any info on what format to use when I use a single channel texture. Is GL_RED faster than GL_BGRA or should i pad my input data (which will take up a whole lot more RAM)?

Comment: GL_RED is single channel (greyscale). If you are displaying a 4K movie I assume you want RGB or YUV data, probably 8bit per channel. So find the closest to that data type. Try GL_BGR or GL_RGB. You would only want GL_RED if you have one texture per channel, this might be useful if you have YUV planar 4:2:0 content.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using 2 or more render targets? Render to one while copying from the other - basically page-flipping, but in reverse. The GPU will stall otherwise. Also, what are you seeing in GPUView or your favorite profiling tool? You (typically) can't copy to host while rendering to the same buffer.

Also, re:mipmaps. You might switch targets based on the camera distance, opting to render to a lower-resolution version where appropriate. It's not the same as generating mips, since you're still dealing with only one version of the texture, not a whole pyramid.

Some more information about your target platform and use case would be helpful. There are a number of vendor-specific libraries and extensions available specifically designed for streaming.

Comment: Thanks for your input, edited with target platform. I don't really see the point in using 2 render targets though. As pointed out here: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/172879-Asynchronous-texture-streaming-using-a-PBO, this should be as efficient as using 1 PBO since the previous buffer is discarded anyways and new storage is asked for.